# gatsby new command error "TypeError: rd.cursorTo is not a function"

Tags: windows, gatsby

Im creating a new site using the command gatsby new and im getting the following error

```
Cloning site template C:\Users\catal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

TypeError: rd.cursorTo is not a function
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\catal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\create-gatsby\lib\index.js:5:852)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

Node.js v18.7.0

Im using windows 11

Answer (score 2):

That was reported in [`gatsbyjs/gatsby` issue 35426](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/35426) in last April (2022), for now without conclusive resolution.

Try the `create-gatsby` locally first, [following its readme](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/create-gatsby#readme), to check if this is a version issue (although [node minimum version was set to 10](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/commit/83d681abbbfe7b791a360c940864c071a443f8e6)).

If possible, try it also in a Linux WSL2 (for instance Ubuntu) VM, in order to check if this is related to the OS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is OS related. Thanks, I didn't know about WSL for windows, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my python version to latest fixed the issue for me.